# Why does Transport.sendMessage fail when one of the addresses is not valid?

Tags: java, email

I am sending mail using following code

```
public void send() throws MessagingException
    {
        // create some properties and get the Session
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", this.getSMTPServer());

        if( this.getDebugMode() )
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        else
            props.put("mail.debug", "false");
        //Comment by Sandip for FIRSTMEDIA-578
        //props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Set Mailer string in Header.. 
        mail.setHeader("X-Mailer", this.getMailer() );

        //Set TO Recipients, toList would be of comma separated if multiple addresses are there
        if( this.getTo() != null )
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.getTo(),",");
            InternetAddress[] recList = new InternetAddress[st.countTokens()];

            for (int r = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); r++)
                recList[r] = new InternetAddress(st.nextToken().trim());          

            if(recList.length != 0 )
            {
                mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recList);
            }

        }           


        //Set CC Recipients, bccList would be of comma separated if multiple addresses are there
        if( this.getCc() != null )
        {
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(this.getCc(),",");
            InternetAddress[] copyList = new InternetAddress[st1.countTokens()];
            for (int c = 0; st1.hasMoreTokens(); c++)
                copyList[c] = new InternetAddress(st1.nextToken().trim());          

            if(copyList.length != 0 )
                mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, copyList);
        }           


        //Set BCC Recipients, bccList would be of comma separated if multiple addresses are there
        if( this.getBcc() != null )
        {
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(this.getBcc(),",");
            InternetAddress[] bcopyList = new InternetAddress[st2.countTokens()];
            for (int c = 0; st2.hasMoreTokens(); c++)
                bcopyList[c] = new InternetAddress(st2.nextToken().trim());          

            if(bcopyList.length != 0 )
                mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bcopyList);
        }   


        // Create a mime message
        mail.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.getFrom()));
        mail.setSubject(subject);


        //create mulitple parts to added
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        //messageMIME can be "text/plain" or "text/html" or anything related to mime
        mbp1.setContent(this.getMsgText(),this.getContentType());
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);

        //Adding attachments to mail
        if( this.attachmentList != null )
        {
            for(int i=0; i < this.attachmentList.size() ; i++ )
            {
                MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
                FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource((File)this.attachmentList.elementAt(i));
                mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
            }
        }

        mail.setContent(mp);
        mail.saveChanges();

        mail.setSentDate(new Date());

        // Send the message
        Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect(this.getSMTPServer(), this.getSMTPUsername(), this.getSMTPPassword());
        trans.sendMessage(mail, mail.getAllRecipients());
        trans.close();

    }
```

With this When mail sending fails to one recipient out of list of recipient all recipient mail send fails.

Is there any change require to send mail to all correct mail recipient from list ?

Comment: is the recipient address invalid? Can you provide a sample case where it's failing?

Comment: not all list but one from list is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Doc](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Transport.html#sendMessage%28javax.mail.Message,%20javax.mail.Address%5B%5D%29), send Message says:
"Send the Message to the specified list of addresses. An appropriate TransportEvent indicating the delivery status is delivered to any TransportListener registered on this Transport. Also, if any of the addresses is invalid, a SendFailedException is thrown. Whether or not the message is still sent succesfully to any valid addresses depends on the Transport implementation. "

You can try to:

- send it onw by one in your code or
- you can catch the exception `SendFailedException` and check
  `getValidUnsentAddresses` to sent to the valid addresses that have
  not been sent.

I really prefer the second one :)

Check [Sent Failed Exception](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html)